# how to generate integer random number in fortran in the range [0,180]?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

```
 I try to use this script but also I got number between 0 to 1 not 0 to 180
```

so what is the solution to this problem

```
 like this `
```

```
code
```

```
    call random_seed()
        do i = 4 , 8
          call random_number(r)
        enddo
        N = 180.
        do i=0, N
         call random_number(alpha1)
        enddo
```

the result between  0 to 1

Comment: Just multiply, really. And round if it should be an integer

Comment: can you explain more as I am a beginner in Fortran sorry

Comment: The Fortran intrinsic subroutine `random_number` returns a floating-point value in the range of [0,1).   If you need an integer in the range [0,180] where 180 is included in the range, then do `call random_number(r); n = 181 * r`.

Comment: Now I understand you,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
call random_number(alpha1)
```

returns a floating point number from interval [0,1)

If you want a floating point number form 0 to 180, just multiply

```
alpha1 = alpha1 * 180
```

The upper bound 180 will not be included but normally it is not a problem with floating point numbers.

---

You did not write whether you need an integer number or a floating point number. I assumed you need a floating point one (like an angle, for example). If you need an integer number, you can round the result using

```
ialpha1 = nint(alpha1)
```

but then the bounds would have smaller probability.

There are 181 integer between (and including) 0 and 180 so you can do

```
alpha1 = alpha1 * 181
ialpha1 = alpha1
```

Comment: Thanks
Muchas Gracias

Comment: Okey perfect 
Another question now I get a value like this 114.58484693478614 
And I want to make a format for it to get it like this 114.58 How?

Comment: @Abd-ElazeemMohamed Please slow down. First try to think about it, read some documentation. After you did that try to formulate a clear question and post it as a new post. Please first try to search on this site, because many problems had been asked and answered before. We have many questions and answers about formats on this site. You may want something like F0.2 or you may need something else. Read first and if it does not suffice, ask.

Comment: I already searched but it makes the result as a column not as I want 
So I will try again, Thanks

Comment: @Abd-ElazeemMohamed You can ask a new question about that but you need to provide more details, your existing code, the output and so on.

Comment: Okey, I will try again and If It is not worked, I will ask again